# Different css animation depending on browser safari or firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, safari

I would like to know how to do so that in Safari the animation of this table looks like in Firefox or Chorme. In chrome or firefox the edge appears from the center of the table In safari the animation is repeated in each th (not tr)

Compare opening this link on each broser (safari and firefox)
Codepen: https://codepen.io/charlysole/pen/LLLqMv

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Company</th>
  <th>Contact</th>
  <th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
  <td>Maria Anders</td>
  <td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
  <td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ernst Handel</td>
  <td>Roland Mendel</td>
  <td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Island Trading</td>
  <td>Helen Bennett</td>
  <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
  <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
  <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
  <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
  <td>Italy</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
    tr {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 2px,0 0, 100% 100%;
  background-position: bottom center, top center, bottom center;
  -webkit-animation: drawBorderFromCenter 4s 0s;
  animation: drawBorderFromCenter 4s 0s;
  background-image: url('http://www.maharam.com/assets/site/swatches/red-8fbb3ee62104ec827fe7ac7b2fc0e5fcdec3376d215c390ff44383c936b869de.gif');
   color: black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes drawBorderFromCenter {
    from {
      background-size: 0 2px, 0 0, 100% 100%;
    }
    to {
      background-size: 100% 2px,0 0, 100% 100%;
    }
 }
```

In safari the lines are drawn from the center of each cell of the table, while in firefox chrome and others draws the line from the center of the entire row (which is how it is expected to be done)

Comment: Do you remember how did you solve it? Same issue here